# Android: Creating radioButtons during runtime in java code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, runtime

I'm trying to create radioButtons. The thing is the number of radioButtons I want to create is variable. As a consequence, I should implement their creation in the java code of my android project (not in the xml). 
My problem is I'm not sure how I'm supposed to add these radioButtons to the UI.

```
for(int i=0; i< quizQuestion.getAnswers().size(); i++){
        radioButtons[i]  = new RadioButton(this);
        rb[i].setText(quizQuestion.getAnswers().get(i));

        //How do I add this to the UI?
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any code you can show us? what have you tried so far?

Comment: I just created the radioButtons really

Comment: You mean you found the solution to your problem? Please share the code so others can benefit from it.

Comment: Nope. Ijust created the radioButtons but I have a missing part in my for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example. I hope that helps.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ////

        LinearLayout radioPanel= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.radioPanel);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            RadioButton radioButton=new RadioButton(this);

            radioButton.setSelected(false);

            radioButton.setLeft(16);
            radioButton.setRight(16);

            radioButton.setText("RadioButton "+ i);

            //Here you add these radioButton to the UI
            radioPanel.addView(radioButton);
        }


        ////

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/contentPanel"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">







<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />



<!--For RadioButton Content Area. (LinearLayout)-->

<!--You can use other layouts. This is just one example.-->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/radioPanel"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

</LinearLayout>




<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioPanel"
    android:text="New Button 2"

    />
```